# Why is my Ant classpath ok in Eclipse but empty on Jenkins?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jenkins

I am running my Ant `build.xml` file both locally and on a server running Jenkins.

Locally, inside Eclipse, the build works wonderfully. I set the classpath using:

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>
```

and then I use the following when I run a target:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath refid="classpath" />
</javac>
```

When I debug using `echo` the classpath shows all the available jars which are in my `project/lib` folder.

However, when I Jenkins fetches this `build.xml` file and runs it remotely, it prints an empty classpath (using the same `echo` target).

Why do my class paths differ based on Eclipse versus Jenkins?

Comment: what is your operation system? If you use unix like OS, you can check file permission.

Comment: I am on Unix, but if Jenkins can access the build.xml file and all of my source files it should be able to access my lib folder.

Comment: I see 2 possible problems, both related to ${lib.dir}: if it's relative path, might differ based on "current" directory where build is running - as it might differ in eclipse/jenkins (as pointed here: I would try to print ${basedir}). If it's absolute, there might be problem in different folder structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your build environment on you Jenkins server is going to look a bit different from your desktop dev env.

Sanity check: where/how is ${lib.dir} provided with a value? 
Usually it is set with a property in the build file - can you maybe post that here also?

Comment: Yes, a property file. It equates to `lib.dir=lib` EDIT: It is on the same directory level as build.xml.

Comment: Ok, maybe try `lib.dir=./lib`. Also perhaps try to echo the value of the lib.dir along with the classpath

Comment: After testing what you and Peter said, I printed three things (classpath, base directory, and library directory) on both Eclipse and Jenkins. The classpath is empty on Jenkins but correct on Eclipse. The library directory is the same on both. The base directory is different leading up on both, but the final folder (my main project folder) is the same. EG: `****/****/***/project` and `home/***/****/project`. So I don't think it's a location issue...

Comment: Ok, so much for the easy solutions :D Next thing to check is where is Jenkins actually building the project. Check the workspace of your job to make sure the lib folder is present there, with all required passengers?

Comment: Please don't hate me. The .jars weren't uploaded because my .gitignore contained a *.jar rule. Thanks for your help - it works now. :|